# How to set up geben for Emacs on Windows?

Tags: emacs, xdebug, geben

I have problems setting up [geben-on-emacs](http://code.google.com/p/geben-on-emacs/) on Windows.
I have:

- GNU Emacs 23.0.60.1
- geben 0.22
- xampp 1.7.0
- Xdebug 2.0.4

Native [Debugclient](http://xdebug.org/docs/install#debugclient) is working fine: debug session gets established and I can issue various debug commands.

This is what happens when I try to debug with geben:

- Issue **M-x geben**. Get *Waiting for debug server to connect at port 9000* response.
- Open `http://localhost/test.php?XDEBUG_SESSION_START=mydebug` in browser.

At this stage PHP script gets loaded but the minor mode doesn't get set geben-mode. So SPC, i, o, r, g etc don't work. If I try to issue commands manually (e.g. `M-x geben-run`) nothing happens. I can switch to *GEBEN<127.0.0.1:900: buffer and enter [DBGp](http://xdebug.org/docs-dbgp.php) commands manually though.

Messages buffer has this line, not sure if it is relevant:

> Unable to load color "brightblue"

What do I do wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Version 0.23](http://code.google.com/p/geben-on-emacs/downloads/list) fixes it.

See http://groups.google.com/group/geben-users/browse_thread/thread/cf0f377665d2a262#

Answer (score 0):

My Emacs (GNU Emacs 22.3.1) doesn't have brightblue as a colour either.  Try searching the lisp for brightblue and just change it to blue.

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't fix the problem. The error message is gone though.